How are alternatives to constitutional originalism justified?
I don't know much about law. Today I was reading some of the U.S. Constitution here.
There were some parts I found genuinely surprising. For example:

No Person shall be a Representative who shall not have attained to the Age of twenty five Years, and been seven Years a Citizen of the United States, and who shall not, when elected, be an Inhabitant of that State in which he shall be chosen.

The use of the word "he", to me, would seem to imply that the Constitution assumes that a "Representative" is male.

Representatives and direct Taxes shall be apportioned among the several States which may be included within this Union, according to their respective Numbers, which shall be determined by adding to the whole Number of free Persons, including those bound to Service for a Term of Years, and excluding Indians not taxed, three fifths of all other Persons.

This appears to say that the number of representatives, and the amount of "direct tax" (I am unsure what exactly that is), is determined by the number of "free persons" in a given state. It does not say "US Citizens", for example. It also includes "those bound to service for a term of years". It sounds like this implies that it is the general population of the state that should be taken into account, including immigrants. I don't know how this compares to the actual governmental practices today.

The Congress shall have Power To... provide for calling forth the Militia to execute the Laws of the Union, suppress Insurrections and repel Invasions;

This says that Congress has the power to call for the "Militia" to "suppress insurrections". I do not know to what extent nowadays Congress can use the military against people who attempt to rebel against the government in some way.

No State shall... make any Thing but gold and silver Coin a Tender in Payment of Debts

This appears to say that only gold and silver coins are acceptable as repayment of debts.
There are tons more parts of the Constitution that sound like they do not describe the current activities of the U.S. government.
I was curious:
Supposing later sections are adding to the constitution which explicitly say they "supersede" earlier parts, why not just remove the earlier part that no longer holds instead?
I read that people who understand the law to be defined by the constitution are called "originalists".
It is not immediately clear to me how there could be a legally justified alternative to originalism. If the constitution is not taken to be an authoritative source of law, it seems like it would lose credibility. In other words, claiming that parts of the constitution are not legally obligatory implies that the constitution itself is not legally obligatory.
Is the reality that the Supreme Court can rule however they want on various cases that come before them, and ultimately, the legal system is not actually bound to following the constitution?

This is a question of interpretation. The census does include all people residents in the state, regardless of citizenship. It's currently a point of contention, but any changes to that failed specifically because of this constitutional demand. The clause about gold and silver applies to states, but states nowadays don't issue any money at all.

"I read that people who understand the law to be defined by the constitution are called "originalists"." This is definitely not true. Also, e.g., "The use of the word "he", to me, would seem to imply that the Constitution assumes that a "Representative" is male." No leading theory of constitutional interpretation would reach that conclusion - "he" had a gender inclusive sense until recently.

This seems like it should be split up into multiple questions as the answers will be different for the different issues you ask.

"The use of the word "he", to me, would seem to imply that the Constitution assumes that a "Representative" is male": then you have presumably never heard of the longstanding practice of using the masculine gender when the gender of the actual person is unknown or indeterminate.  If you don't allow "he" to refer to females then you wouldn't be able to convict women of many crimes, either.

Various theories of constitutional interpretation

I read that people who understand the law to be defined by the
constitution are called "originalists".

This is just wrong.
There are various theories of constitutional interpretation including originalism, textualism which is a subset of originalism, and "living constitutionalism" (this is not a complete list).
"Living constitutionalism" focuses on the underlying ideas represented by the words as interpreted in light of modern realities. Thus, a "free press" could include digital publications that don't use a physical printing press, the authorization of the Congress to create an Army and a Navy can include the authorization to create an "Air Force" or "Space Force" even though both would have been impossible in 1789 (when the current constitution was adopted). In this analysis, the 8th Amendment protection against cruel and unusual punishment depends upon what is cruel and unusual in the current context and not only what was cruel and unusual in 1791 when the 8th Amendment took effect.
This is actually the leading method of constitutional interpretation in practice and is pervasive in constitutional interpretation. It was especially prominent during the Warren Court era in a liberal direction, and during the Lochner Court era in a conservative direction.
Most notably, the application of the federal bill of rights to state and local governments and their officials in most cases, called the "selective incorporation doctrine" is basically a living constitutionalist concept. The official retcon legal theory is that the bill of rights began to apply to the state via the due process clause of the 14th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution, although in reality, this didn't start to happen until decades later in the 1910s and the 14th Amendment was probably not intended to have the effect it has since been given as a matter of historical reality.
Another example is the one man, one vote rule for state legislative districts, which was gleaned from the idea of equal protection in the 14th Amendment in the 1960s, despite the fact that when the 14th Amendment was adopted a century earlier, it was not widely believed that, for example, a state constitution that allocated seats in a state senate one per county following the model of the federal constitution was made immediately unconstitutional.
Roe  v. Wade and some other "substantive due process" cases like Griswold (right to contraception) and Loving v. Virginia (disallowing bans on interracial marriage) were all based upon some rather high level generalizations of what the U.S. Constitution and Bill of Rights protected even if the specific issues addressed in those cases didn't have express constitutional language to articulate them.
The expansive reading given to federal government authority under the Interstate Commerce Clause is another example of Living Constitutionalism, which is driven, in part, by modern economic theory and in part by the reality that activities within a single state can affect interstate commerce in a way that it didn't in the 18th century.
"Originalism" which was originally developed as a distinct mode of constitutional interpretation, was developed in response to the Civil Rights Movement and seeks to freeze in place the meaning that the educated public would have been placed on constitutional provisions at the time that they were adopted - the so called "public original meaning". It calls for a narrower interpretation of the constitution than a living constitutionalist reading (although, in practice, the dividing line is never clear cut, even originalists don't have a problem with the existence of the Air Force). It was a response to the feeling that the Supreme Court had implied too many rights into the constitution.
More generally, self-proclaimed "originalists" are really only originalist when it suits them. The decision in Trump v. Anderson, for example, was not an originalist interpretation of Section 3 of the 14th Amendment (the insurrection clause), even though the conservative justices on the U.S. Supreme Court claim to be originalist. Neither was its recent decision on presidential immunity from criminal liability. Neither is the unitary executive theory which is advanced mostly by self-proclaimed originalists or textualists. The decision to apply the Second Amendment to the U.S. Constitution to state and local governments, when that was clearly not the original intent and despite the fact that it is a poor fit the previous precedents regarding when the provisions of the Bill of Rights are applied to the state is likewise far afield of actual originalism.
A fair amount of overlap between originalism and living constitutionalism involves the fact that many provisions of the U.S. Constitution and Bill of Rights were specifically drafted against the backdrop of English legal practices that the Founders sought to disallow in their governmental system.
"Textualism" has a subtle difference focusing on the original meaning of the words and not the intent of the drafters of those words:

One is “original intent” that says we should interpret the
Constitution based on what its drafters originally intended when they
wrote it. The other is that we should interpret the Constitution based
on the original meaning of the text—not necessarily what the Founders
intended, but how the words they used would have generally been
understood at the time.
Both versions of originalism—original intent and original
meaning—contend that the Constitution has permanent, static meaning
that’s baked into the text. Originalism, in either iteration, is in
direct contravention of the “Living Constitution” theory.

A good example of non-textualist originalism is the 11th Amendment, which was intended to give states sovereign immunity from suit as well as immunity from a non-SCOTUS federal court forum (and has been interpreted in that way), even though it reads as a mere modification of federal court jurisdiction.
Textualism arises mostly out of the concern that without a grounding in the actual language of the constitution, the constitution is susceptible to manipulation based upon secret insider accounts of the drafters' legislative intents which is too easily manipulated.
Textualism aspired to limit court expanded rights even more strictly than originalism, although sometimes textualism will honor rights that are clearly mandated by constitutional language even though the language wasn't initially intended to have the effect (such as the one man, one vote cases, which are consistent with textualism but not with originalism).
"Structuralism" is an approach to constitutional interpretation based upon what is logical under the circumstances in light of the structure of the government that the constitution sets forth, particularly in the case of separation of powers and federalism issues.
Other approaches emphasize judicial precedents, historical practices, moral reasoning, the U.S. national identity or ethos, and pragmatic considerations.
Old-fashioned words and some specific examples.
All theories of constitutional interpretation recognize that the meaning of words may change over time. For example, in the 18th century, the word "he" which is now predominantly gendered (as of the last 30-40 years), at the time had a widely understood gender neutral sense that applied to any person.
Similarly, the emoluments clauses of the U.S. Constitution are interpreted in light of the meaning of the word "emoluments" in 1789, and subsequent treatment of those clauses in practice, even though the term has almost completely dropped out of common English language usage.
For constitutional purposes, the term militia when used as cited in the question refers to the Army National Guard and Air Force National Guard, although the meaning of "militia" was not always so clear, and customarily included an unorganized militia of all able bodied men in a certain age range who could be called up and conscripted in the circumstances indicated. Notably, the constitution and the bill of rights also pre-date the existence of organized police forces which are mostly a post-U.S. Civil War institution. These days, either a state governor or the President can call up the National Guard to address some mission.
The U.S. Constitution and Bill of Rights also predate anything that would be recognizable of immigration laws today, although authority to govern immigration was vested in Congress. There were citizens, non-citizens who were free persons, and slaves. But, the notion of being an "illegal immigrant" didn't real exist then. Under the existing constitution, which eliminated slavery and under 1924 legislation that eliminated the "Indians Not Taxed" clause, everyone who is domiciled in a state is a resident of the state for census purposes regardless of immigration status.
The meaning of the term "direct tax" is arcane and still a matter of some debate. A direct tax was distinct from an excise tax or a customs duty, and is certainly included income taxes, but there were lots of gray areas.
The provision that states: "No State shall... make any Thing but gold and silver Coin a Tender in Payment of Debts" was intended to and did, create a federal government monopoly on establishing a currency. Gold and silver coins would just be raw metals. Another provision of the constitution provides that the federal government can create a currency which is also legal tender in payment of debts. It does not say that only gold and silver coins are acceptable as repayment of debts. The key to understanding this is reading the entire Constitution as a whole and not just isolated bits of it.
The "full edit trail" stylistic preference

Supposing later sections are adding to the constitution which
explicitly say they "supersede" earlier parts, why not just remove the
earlier part that no longer holds instead?

This is just a style choice. The other parts are removed from the constitution. But essentially, the predominant way this is done among lawyers is to have a full edit trail widely available. For example, the Constitutional Amendment repealing prohibition didn't just repeal prohibition, it also affirmatively granted the right to states to regulate alcohol without undue federal government interference. The "full edit trail" style choice makes sure that details like this don't get lost.
Who has the last word on constitutional interpretation?

Is the reality that the Supreme Court can rule however they want on
various cases that come before them, and ultimately, the legal system
is not actually bound to following the constitution?

As a practical and institutional matter, yes, this is the case. The Supreme Court is the final authority upon what the constitution means and its interpretation is, by definition, the correct one.
For lower courts, adherence to supreme court precedent overrides all other interpretative considerations.
To the extent, however, that the U.S. Supreme Court honors its past precedents under the principle of stare decisis, past SCOTUS precedents based upon different theories of constitutional interpretation applied at the time are all part of constitutional law in the U.S.
There are theories of constitutional interpretation in which Congress and the President have co-equal rights to interpret the U.S. Constitution with the U.S. Supreme Court. But, in practice, these have never had much practical impact, and have not been widely adopted.
